# How to recycle/reuse CUDA threads

Tags: cuda

In CUDA, how does one create a barrier for all threads in a kernel to wait on, until the *CPU* sends a signal to that barrier that it's safe/helpful to proceed?

I would like to avoid the overhead of launching a CUDA kernel.  There are two types of overhead to avoid: (1) the cost of simply launching the kernel on X blocks and Y threads, and (2) the time it takes me to reinitialize my shared memory, which will largely have the same contents between invocations.

We do recycle/re-use threads all the time in CPU workloads.  And CUDA even provides `event` synchronization primitives.  Perhaps it would be minimal hardware cost to provide a more traditional signaling object.

Here's some code that provides a hole for the concept that I seek.  The reader will probably want to search for `QUESTION IS HERE`.  Building it in Nsight requires setting the Device Linker Mode to Separate Compilation (at least, I found it necessary).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <cuda.h>

static void CheckCudaErrorAux (const char *, unsigned, const char *, cudaError_t);
#define CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(value) CheckCudaErrorAux(__FILE__,__LINE__, #value, value)

const int COUNT_DOWN_ITERATIONS = 1000;
const int KERNEL_MAXIMUM_LOOPS = 5; // IRL, we'd set this large enough to prevent hitting this value, unless the kernel is externally terminated
const int SIGNALS_TO_SEND_COUNT = 3;
const int BLOCK_COUNT = 1;
const int THREADS_PER_BLOCK = 2;

__device__ void count_down(int * shared_location_to_ensure_side_effect) {
    int x = *shared_location_to_ensure_side_effect;
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT_DOWN_ITERATIONS; ++i) {
        x += i;
    }
    *shared_location_to_ensure_side_effect = x;
}

/**
 * CUDA kernel waits for events and then counts down upon receiving them.
 */
__global__ void kernel(cudaStream_t stream, cudaEvent_t go_event, cudaEvent_t done_event, int ** cuda_malloc_managed_int_address) {
    __shared__ int local_copy_of_cuda_malloc_managed_int_address; // we always start at 0

    printf("Block %i, Thread %i: entered kernel\n", blockIdx.x, threadIdx.x);
    for (int i = 0; i < KERNEL_MAXIMUM_LOOPS; ++i) {
        printf("Block %i, Thread %i: entered loop; waitin 4 go_event\n", blockIdx.x, threadIdx.x);

        // QUESTION IS HERE: I want this to block on receiving a signal from the
        // CPU, indicating that work is ready to be done
        cudaStreamWaitEvent(stream, go_event, cudaEventBlockingSync);

        printf("Block %i, Thread %i:      in loop; received go_event\n", blockIdx.x, threadIdx.x);
        if (i == 0) { // we have received the signal and data is ready to be interpreted
            local_copy_of_cuda_malloc_managed_int_address = cuda_malloc_managed_int_address[blockIdx.x][threadIdx.x];
        }
        count_down(&local_copy_of_cuda_malloc_managed_int_address);
        printf("Block %i, Thread %i:      finished counting\n", blockIdx.x, threadIdx.x);
        cudaEventRecord(done_event, stream);
        printf("Block %i, Thread %i:      recorded event; may loop back\n", blockIdx.x, threadIdx.x);
    }
    printf("Block %i, Thread %i: copying result %i back to managed memory\n", blockIdx.x, threadIdx.x, local_copy_of_cuda_malloc_managed_int_address);
    cuda_malloc_managed_int_address[blockIdx.x][threadIdx.x] = local_copy_of_cuda_malloc_managed_int_address;
    printf("Block %i, Thread %i: exiting kernel\n", blockIdx.x, threadIdx.x);
}


int main(void)
{

    int ** data;
    cudaMallocManaged(&data, BLOCK_COUNT * sizeof(int *));
    for (int b = 0; b < BLOCK_COUNT; ++b)
        cudaMallocManaged(&(data[b]), THREADS_PER_BLOCK * sizeof(int));

    cudaEvent_t go_event;
    cudaEventCreateWithFlags(&go_event, cudaEventBlockingSync);

    cudaEvent_t done_event;
    cudaEventCreateWithFlags(&done_event, cudaEventBlockingSync);

    cudaStream_t stream;
    cudaStreamCreate(&stream);

    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaDeviceSynchronize());  // probably unnecessary

    printf("CPU: spawning kernel\n");
    kernel<<<BLOCK_COUNT, THREADS_PER_BLOCK, sizeof(int), stream>>>(stream, go_event, done_event, data);


    for (int i = 0; i < SIGNALS_TO_SEND_COUNT; ++i) {
        usleep(4 * 1000 * 1000); // accepts time in microseconds

        // Simulate the sending of the "next" piece of work
        data[0][0] = i;      // unrolled, because it's easier to read
        data[0][1] = i + 1;  // unrolled, because it's easier to read

        printf("CPU: sending go_event\n");
        cudaEventRecord(go_event, stream);
        cudaStreamWaitEvent(stream, done_event, cudaEventBlockingSync); // doesn't block even though I wish it would
    }

    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    for (int b = 0; b < BLOCK_COUNT; ++b) {
        for (int t = 0; t < THREADS_PER_BLOCK; ++t) {
            printf("Result for Block %i and Thread %i: %i\n", b, t, data[b][t]);
        }
    }

    for (int b = 0; b < BLOCK_COUNT; ++b)
        cudaFree(data[b]);
    cudaFree(data);

    cudaEventDestroy(done_event);
    cudaEventDestroy(go_event);
    cudaStreamDestroy(stream);

    printf("CPU: exiting program");

    return 0;
}

/**
 * Check the return value of the CUDA runtime API call and exit
 * the application if the call has failed.
 */
static void CheckCudaErrorAux (const char *file, unsigned line, const char *statement, cudaError_t err)
{
    if (err == cudaSuccess)
        return;
    std::cerr << statement<<" returned " << cudaGetErrorString(err) << "("<<err<< ") at "<<file<<":"<<line << std::endl;
    exit (1);
}
```

And here is the output from running it.  Note that the outputs are "wrong", simply because they were over-written by the loop whose signal is supposed to be the blocking mechanism for the GPU threads.

```
CPU: spawning kernel
Block 0, Thread 0: entered kernel
Block 0, Thread 1: entered kernel
Block 0, Thread 0: entered loop; waitin 4 go_event
Block 0, Thread 1: entered loop; waitin 4 go_event
Block 0, Thread 0:      in loop; received go_event
Block 0, Thread 1:      in loop; received go_event
Block 0, Thread 0:      finished counting
Block 0, Thread 1:      finished counting
Block 0, Thread 0:      recorded event; may loop back
Block 0, Thread 1:      recorded event; may loop back
Block 0, Thread 0: entered loop; waitin 4 go_event
Block 0, Thread 1: entered loop; waitin 4 go_event
Block 0, Thread 0:      in loop; received go_event
Block 0, Thread 1:      in loop; received go_event
Block 0, Thread 0:      finished counting
Block 0, Thread 1:      finished counting
Block 0, Thread 0:      recorded event; may loop back
Block 0, Thread 1:      recorded event; may loop back
Block 0, Thread 0: entered loop; waitin 4 go_event
Block 0, Thread 1: entered loop; waitin 4 go_event
Block 0, Thread 0:      in loop; received go_event
Block 0, Thread 1:      in loop; received go_event
Block 0, Thread 0:      finished counting
Block 0, Thread 1:      finished counting
Block 0, Thread 0:      recorded event; may loop back
Block 0, Thread 1:      recorded event; may loop back
Block 0, Thread 0: entered loop; waitin 4 go_event
Block 0, Thread 1: entered loop; waitin 4 go_event
Block 0, Thread 0:      in loop; received go_event
Block 0, Thread 1:      in loop; received go_event
Block 0, Thread 0:      finished counting
Block 0, Thread 1:      finished counting
Block 0, Thread 0:      recorded event; may loop back
Block 0, Thread 1:      recorded event; may loop back
Block 0, Thread 0: entered loop; waitin 4 go_event
Block 0, Thread 1: entered loop; waitin 4 go_event
Block 0, Thread 0:      in loop; received go_event
Block 0, Thread 1:      in loop; received go_event
Block 0, Thread 0:      finished counting
Block 0, Thread 1:      finished counting
Block 0, Thread 0:      recorded event; may loop back
Block 0, Thread 1:      recorded event; may loop back
Block 0, Thread 0: copying result 2497500 back to managed memory
Block 0, Thread 1: copying result 2497500 back to managed memory
Block 0, Thread 0: exiting kernel
Block 0, Thread 1: exiting kernel
CPU: sending go_event
CPU: sending go_event
CPU: sending go_event
Result for Block 0 and Thread 0: 2
Result for Block 0 and Thread 1: 3
CPU: exiting program
```

Comment: Please ignore the fact that all threads are writing their result to the same `__shared__` address.  I'd fix it, but it's simpler this way anyway.

Comment: The canonical methods to synchronize all threads in a grid are 1. the kernel launch itself, or 2. a CUDA cooperative kernel launch, part of the CUDA [cooperative groups](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/cooperative-groups/) API, and use of a grid-wide sync that is enabled in that sort of launch.  Note that a cooperative kernel launch is only available in certain supported scenarios, basically linux or Windows TCC mode, on Pascal or Volta devices.

Comment: That looks interesting, and the answer may be within.  I just want to clarify that this is fundamentally a synchronization problem between the CPU and GPU (as opposed to between threads).

Comment: Both are potentially involved.  I was responding to this snip from your first sentence: `how does one create a barrier for all blocks+threads in a kernel to wait on`.  If you actually want to do that, I refer you to my previous comment.  In order to guarantee that all threads in a kernel will reach a barrier, and wait there (for whatever it is you want them to wait on), requires one of those mechanisms (for correctness).  If that is not actually your requirement, then you may be able to get by with something less.

Comment: Are you on windows or on linux?  What GPU are you running on?  Which CUDA version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this answer.  I plan to delete the first one after reaching a consensus, as I hope its only value will be historical.

One possible implementation is to have a set of flags or integer in the device memory. The CUDA threads would block (e.g., by calling clock64()) until the flag/integer reaches a certain value, indicating that there is more work for the CUDA thread to process. This would probably be slower than using a first-class CUDA-provided synchronization primitive but faster than reinitializing my **shared** memory with each kernel invocation. It also involves some sort of busy wait/sleep mechanism, which I'm not thrilled about.

Here's an implementation that appears to be working -- though, I'm concerned that I'm relying upon some undefined behavior of managed memory that happens to  benefit the program's execution. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <cuda.h>

#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

static void CheckCudaErrorAux (const char *, unsigned, const char *, cudaError_t);
#define CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(value) CheckCudaErrorAux(__FILE__,__LINE__, #value, value)

const int COUNT_DOWN_ITERATIONS = 1000;
const int KERNEL_MAXIMUM_LOOPS = 1000; // IRL, we'd set this large enough to prevent hitting this value, unless the kernel is externally terminated
const int SIGNALS_TO_SEND_COUNT = 1000;
const int BLOCK_COUNT = 1;
const int THREADS_PER_BLOCK = 2;

__device__ void count_down(int * shared_location_to_ensure_side_effect) {
    int x = *shared_location_to_ensure_side_effect;
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT_DOWN_ITERATIONS; ++i) {
        x += i;
    }
    *shared_location_to_ensure_side_effect = x;
}


__device__ void clock_block(clock_t clock_count)
{
    clock_t start_clock = clock64();
    while (clock64() - start_clock < clock_count);
}

/**
 * CUDA kernel waits for flag to increment and then counts down.
 */
__global__ void spawn_worker_threads(int ** cuda_malloc_managed_int_address, int * cuda_malloc_managed_go_flag, int * cuda_malloc_managed_done_flag) {
    __shared__ int local_copy_of_cuda_malloc_managed_int_address; // we always start at 0

    volatile int * my_go_flag = cuda_malloc_managed_go_flag;
    volatile int * volatile_done_flag = cuda_malloc_managed_done_flag;

    printf("Block %i, Thread %i: entered kernel\n", blockIdx.x, threadIdx.x);
    for (int i = 0; i < KERNEL_MAXIMUM_LOOPS; ++i) {
        while (*my_go_flag <= i) {
            clock_block(10000); // in cycles, not seconds!
        }

        if (i == 0) { // we have received the signal and data is ready to be interpreted
            local_copy_of_cuda_malloc_managed_int_address = cuda_malloc_managed_int_address[blockIdx.x][threadIdx.x];
        }
        count_down(&local_copy_of_cuda_malloc_managed_int_address);

        // Wait for all worker threads to finish and then signal readiness for new work
        __syncthreads(); // TODO: sync with other blocks too

        if (blockIdx.x == 0 && threadIdx.x == 0)
            *volatile_done_flag  = *volatile_done_flag + 1;
        //__threadfence_system(); // based on the documentation, it's not clear that this should actually help
    }
    printf("Block %i, Thread %i: copying result %i back to managed memory\n", blockIdx.x, threadIdx.x, local_copy_of_cuda_malloc_managed_int_address);
    cuda_malloc_managed_int_address[blockIdx.x][threadIdx.x] = local_copy_of_cuda_malloc_managed_int_address;
    printf("Block %i, Thread %i: exiting kernel\n", blockIdx.x, threadIdx.x);
}


int main(void)
{

    int ** data;
    cudaMallocManaged(&data, BLOCK_COUNT * sizeof(int *));
    for (int b = 0; b < BLOCK_COUNT; ++b)
        cudaMallocManaged(&(data[b]), THREADS_PER_BLOCK * sizeof(int));

    int * go_flag;
    int * done_flag;
    cudaMallocManaged(&go_flag, sizeof(int));
    cudaMallocManaged(&done_flag, sizeof(int));

    volatile int * my_volatile_done_flag = done_flag;

    printf("CPU: spawning kernel\n");
    spawn_worker_threads<<<BLOCK_COUNT, THREADS_PER_BLOCK>>>(data, go_flag, done_flag);

    // The cudaMemAdvise calls seem to be unnecessary, but they make it ~13% faster
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaMemAdvise(go_flag, sizeof(int), cudaMemAdviseSetPreferredLocation, cudaCpuDeviceId));
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaMemAdvise(done_flag, sizeof(int), cudaMemAdviseSetPreferredLocation, cudaCpuDeviceId));


    for (int i = 0; i < SIGNALS_TO_SEND_COUNT; ++i) {
        if (i % 50 == 0) printf("============== CPU: On iteration %i ============\n", i);

        // Simulate the writing of the "next" piece of work
        data[0][0] = i;      // unrolled, because it's easier to read this way
        data[0][1] = i + 1;  // unrolled, because it's easier to read

        *go_flag = *go_flag + 1; // since it's monotonically increasing, and only written to by the CPU code, this is fine

        while (*my_volatile_done_flag < i)
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(50));
    }
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    for (int b = 0; b < BLOCK_COUNT; ++b)
        for (int t = 0; t < THREADS_PER_BLOCK; ++t)
            printf("Result for Block %i and Thread %i: %i\n", b, t, data[b][t]);

    for (int b = 0; b < BLOCK_COUNT; ++b)
        cudaFree(data[b]);
    cudaFree(data);
    cudaFree(go_flag);
    cudaFree(done_flag);

    printf("CPU: exiting program");

    return 0;
}

/**
 * Check the return value of the CUDA runtime API call and exit
 * the application if the call has failed.
 */
static void CheckCudaErrorAux (const char *file, unsigned line, const char *statement, cudaError_t err)
{
    if (err == cudaSuccess)
        return;
    std::cerr << statement<<" returned " << cudaGetErrorString(err) << "("<<err<< ") at "<<file<<":"<<line << std::endl;
    exit (1);
}
```

And here's the output, which talks about 50ms to generate.  That's about 50 microseconds per "recycling" which is well-within my real application's tolerance.

```
Starting timer for Synchronization timer
CPU: spawning kernel
============== CPU: On iteration 0 ============
============== CPU: On iteration 50 ============
============== CPU: On iteration 100 ============
============== CPU: On iteration 150 ============
============== CPU: On iteration 200 ============
============== CPU: On iteration 250 ============
============== CPU: On iteration 300 ============
============== CPU: On iteration 350 ============
============== CPU: On iteration 400 ============
============== CPU: On iteration 450 ============
============== CPU: On iteration 500 ============
============== CPU: On iteration 550 ============
============== CPU: On iteration 600 ============
============== CPU: On iteration 650 ============
============== CPU: On iteration 700 ============
============== CPU: On iteration 750 ============
============== CPU: On iteration 800 ============
============== CPU: On iteration 850 ============
============== CPU: On iteration 900 ============
============== CPU: On iteration 950 ============
Block 0, Thread 0: entered kernel
Block 0, Thread 1: entered kernel
Block 0, Thread 0: copying result 499500001 back to managed memory
Block 0, Thread 1: copying result 499500001 back to managed memory
Block 0, Thread 0: exiting kernel
Block 0, Thread 1: exiting kernel
Result for Block 0 and Thread 0: 499500001
Result for Block 0 and Thread 1: 499500001
CPU: exiting program
```

Thanks to @einpoklum and @robertcrovella for suggesting the use of `volatile`.  It seems to be working, but I'm inexperienced with `volatile`.   Based on what I've read, this is a valid and correct usage that should result in defined behavior.  Would y'all mind please confirming or correcting this conclusion?

Comment: Where is your kernel using go_event or done_event (When I remove all the debug and commented-out code)? Also, please write a version of the code with no debugging and printing, such that I could easily use it with arbitrary `__device__` function to be run one the CPU signals us.

Comment: Also,  consider using the [CUDA Runtime API modern C++ wrappers](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers/) for clarify and terseness. Caveat: I'm the author of those.

Comment: Neat wrappers @einpoklum!  I'll update the code to have more consistent variable names tomorrow so that it's clearer where the variables are used.

Answer (score 0):

READ THE OTHER ANSWER FIRST.  This answer is only still here for historical reference.  I'll either downvote it or delete it soon.

One possible implementation is to have a set of flags or integer in the device memory.  The CUDA threads would block (perhaps by calling `clock64()`) until the flag/integer reaches a certain value, indicating that there is more work for the CUDA thread to process.  This would probably be slower than using a first-class CUDA-provided synchronization primitive but faster than reinitializing my `__shared__` memory with each kernel invocation.  It also involves some sort of busy wait/sleep mechanism, which I'm not thrilled about.

Follow-up: It appears to be working -- some of the time (`printf` calls seem to help).  I'm guessing there's some undefined behavior in managed memory that's benefiting me.  Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <cuda.h>

static void CheckCudaErrorAux (const char *, unsigned, const char *, cudaError_t);
#define CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(value) CheckCudaErrorAux(__FILE__,__LINE__, #value, value)

const int COUNT_DOWN_ITERATIONS = 1000;
const int KERNEL_MAXIMUM_LOOPS = 5; // IRL, we'd set this large enough to prevent hitting this value, unless the kernel is externally terminated
const int SIGNALS_TO_SEND_COUNT = 3;
const int BLOCK_COUNT = 1;
const int THREADS_PER_BLOCK = 2;

__device__ void count_down(int * shared_location_to_ensure_side_effect) {
    int x = *shared_location_to_ensure_side_effect;
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT_DOWN_ITERATIONS; ++i) {
        x += i;
    }
    *shared_location_to_ensure_side_effect = x;
}


__device__ void clock_block(clock_t clock_count)
{
    //printf("time used so far: %lu\n", clock64());
    clock_t start_clock = clock64();
    while (clock64() - start_clock < clock_count);
}

/**
 * CUDA kernel waits for flag to increment and then counts down.
 */
__global__ void kernel_block_via_flag(cudaStream_t stream, cudaEvent_t go_event, cudaEvent_t done_event, int ** cuda_malloc_managed_int_address, int * cuda_malloc_managed_synchronization_flag) {
    __shared__ int local_copy_of_cuda_malloc_managed_int_address; // we always start at 0

    printf("Block %i, Thread %i: entered kernel\n", blockIdx.x, threadIdx.x);
    for (int i = 0; i < KERNEL_MAXIMUM_LOOPS; ++i) {
        printf("Block %i, Thread %i: entered loop; waitin 4 go_event\n", blockIdx.x, threadIdx.x);
        while (*cuda_malloc_managed_synchronization_flag <= i)

            //printf("%lu\n", *cuda_malloc_managed_synchronization_flag);
            clock_block(1000000000); // in cycles, not seconds!

        cudaStreamWaitEvent(stream, go_event, cudaEventBlockingSync);
        printf("Block %i, Thread %i:      in loop; received go_event\n", blockIdx.x, threadIdx.x);

        if (i == 0) { // we have received the signal and data is ready to be interpreted
            local_copy_of_cuda_malloc_managed_int_address = cuda_malloc_managed_int_address[blockIdx.x][threadIdx.x];
        }
        count_down(&local_copy_of_cuda_malloc_managed_int_address);
        printf("Block %i, Thread %i:      finished counting\n", blockIdx.x, threadIdx.x);
        cudaEventRecord(done_event, stream);
        printf("Block %i, Thread %i:      recorded event; may loop back\n", blockIdx.x, threadIdx.x);
    }
    printf("Block %i, Thread %i: copying result %i back to managed memory\n", blockIdx.x, threadIdx.x, local_copy_of_cuda_malloc_managed_int_address);
    cuda_malloc_managed_int_address[blockIdx.x][threadIdx.x] = local_copy_of_cuda_malloc_managed_int_address;
    printf("Block %i, Thread %i: exiting kernel\n", blockIdx.x, threadIdx.x);
}


int main(void)
{

    int ** data;
    cudaMallocManaged(&data, BLOCK_COUNT * sizeof(int *));
    for (int b = 0; b < BLOCK_COUNT; ++b)
        cudaMallocManaged(&(data[b]), THREADS_PER_BLOCK * sizeof(int));

    cudaEvent_t go_event;
    cudaEventCreateWithFlags(&go_event, cudaEventBlockingSync);

    cudaEvent_t done_event;
    cudaEventCreateWithFlags(&done_event, cudaEventBlockingSync);

    cudaStream_t stream;
    cudaStreamCreate(&stream);

    int * synchronization_flag;
    cudaMallocManaged(&synchronization_flag, sizeof(int));
    //cudaMalloc(&synchronization_flag, sizeof(int));
    //int my_copy_of_synchronization_flag = 0;

    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaDeviceSynchronize());  // probably unnecessary

    printf("CPU: spawning kernel\n");
    kernel_block_via_flag<<<BLOCK_COUNT, THREADS_PER_BLOCK, sizeof(int), stream>>>(stream, go_event, done_event, data, synchronization_flag);
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaMemAdvise(synchronization_flag, sizeof(int), cudaMemAdviseSetPreferredLocation, cudaCpuDeviceId));

    for (int i = 0; i < SIGNALS_TO_SEND_COUNT; ++i) {
        usleep(4 * 1000 * 1000); // accepts time in microseconds

        // Simulate the sending of the "next" piece of work
        data[0][0] = i;      // unrolled, because it's easier to read
        data[0][1] = i + 1;  // unrolled, because it's easier to read

        printf("CPU: sending go_event\n");
        //++my_copy_of_synchronization_flag;
        //CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaMemcpyAsync(synchronization_flag, &my_copy_of_synchronization_flag, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
        *synchronization_flag = *synchronization_flag + 1; // since it's monotonically increasing, and only written to by the CPU code, this is fine
    }

    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    for (int b = 0; b < BLOCK_COUNT; ++b) {
        for (int t = 0; t < THREADS_PER_BLOCK; ++t) {
            printf("Result for Block %i and Thread %i: %i\n", b, t, data[b][t]);
        }
    }

    for (int b = 0; b < BLOCK_COUNT; ++b)
        cudaFree(data[b]);
    cudaFree(data);
    cudaFree(synchronization_flag);

    cudaEventDestroy(done_event);
    cudaEventDestroy(go_event);
    cudaStreamDestroy(stream);

    printf("CPU: exiting program");

    return 0;
}

/**
 * Check the return value of the CUDA runtime API call and exit
 * the application if the call has failed.
 */
static void CheckCudaErrorAux (const char *file, unsigned line, const char *statement, cudaError_t err)
{
    if (err == cudaSuccess)
        return;
    std::cerr << statement<<" returned " << cudaGetErrorString(err) << "("<<err<< ") at "<<file<<":"<<line << std::endl;
    exit (1);
}




__global__ void kernel_block_via_flag(cudaStream_t stream, cudaEvent_t go_event, cudaEvent_t done_event, int ** cuda_malloc_managed_int_address, int * cuda_malloc_managed_synchronization_flag) {
    __shared__ int local_copy_of_cuda_malloc_managed_int_address; // we always start at 0

    printf("Block %i, Thread %i: entered kernel\n", blockIdx.x, threadIdx.x);
    for (int i = 0; i < KERNEL_MAXIMUM_LOOPS; ++i) {
        printf("Block %i, Thread %i: entered loop; waitin 4 go_event\n", blockIdx.x, threadIdx.x);
        while (*cuda_malloc_managed_synchronization_flag <= i)
            //printf("%i\n", *cuda_malloc_managed_synchronization_flag);
            clock_block(1000000000);

        cudaStreamWaitEvent(stream, go_event, cudaEventBlockingSync);
        printf("Block %i, Thread %i:      in loop; received go_event\n", blockIdx.x, threadIdx.x);

        if (i == 0) { // we have received the signal and data is ready to be interpreted
            local_copy_of_cuda_malloc_managed_int_address = cuda_malloc_managed_int_address[blockIdx.x][threadIdx.x];
        }
        count_down(&local_copy_of_cuda_malloc_managed_int_address);
        printf("Block %i, Thread %i:      finished counting\n", blockIdx.x, threadIdx.x);
        cudaEventRecord(done_event, stream);
        printf("Block %i, Thread %i:      recorded event; may loop back\n", blockIdx.x, threadIdx.x);
    }
    printf("Block %i, Thread %i: copying result %i back to managed memory\n", blockIdx.x, threadIdx.x, local_copy_of_cuda_malloc_managed_int_address);
    cuda_malloc_managed_int_address[blockIdx.x][threadIdx.x] = local_copy_of_cuda_malloc_managed_int_address;
    printf("Block %i, Thread %i: exiting kernel\n", blockIdx.x, threadIdx.x);
}
```

And the output:

```
CPU: spawning kernel
Block 0, Thread 0: entered kernel
Block 0, Thread 1: entered kernel
Block 0, Thread 0: entered loop; waitin 4 go_event
Block 0, Thread 1: entered loop; waitin 4 go_event
CPU: sending go_event
Block 0, Thread 0:      in loop; received go_event
Block 0, Thread 1:      in loop; received go_event
Block 0, Thread 0:      finished counting
Block 0, Thread 1:      finished counting
Block 0, Thread 0:      recorded event; may loop back
Block 0, Thread 1:      recorded event; may loop back
Block 0, Thread 0: entered loop; waitin 4 go_event
Block 0, Thread 1: entered loop; waitin 4 go_event
CPU: sending go_event
Block 0, Thread 0:      in loop; received go_event
Block 0, Thread 1:      in loop; received go_event
Block 0, Thread 0:      finished counting
Block 0, Thread 1:      finished counting
Block 0, Thread 0:      recorded event; may loop back
Block 0, Thread 1:      recorded event; may loop back
Block 0, Thread 0: entered loop; waitin 4 go_event
Block 0, Thread 1: entered loop; waitin 4 go_event
CPU: sending go_event
Block 0, Thread 0:      in loop; received go_event
Block 0, Thread 1:      in loop; received go_event
Block 0, Thread 0:      finished counting
Block 0, Thread 1:      finished counting
Block 0, Thread 0:      recorded event; may loop back
Block 0, Thread 1:      recorded event; may loop back
Block 0, Thread 0: entered loop; waitin 4 go_event
Block 0, Thread 1: entered loop; waitin 4 go_event
```

This is still a bad solution.  I hope to accept someone else's answer.

Comment: I coded this up using both `cudaMalloc` and `cudaMallocManaged`, and it seems not to work.  I'm currently poking around to see if there's an advisement I can make to the managed address that will force CUDA to (eventually) update the GPU's view of the allocated integer flag.

Comment: you should mark it with `volatile`, and you may also need extra mechanisms depending on how you update said integer from host code, as well as what platform you are on (e.g. windows WDDM, or not).

Comment: Added a couple aliases and made them volatile.  Also got rid of the async prefetches.  So long as I include debugging info (`-g` and `-G`) it runs 1000 iterations in 202ms, which isn't so bad (so long as it scales).  Of course, when I remove the debugging info, the flag updates fail to percolate through the system, and it stalls out almost immediately.

Comment: @ragerdl: You haven't actually made anything volatile... change your answers.

Comment: Also, have you considered having the threads "sleep" by just repeatedly reading the volatile value in global memory?

Comment: @einpoklum Indeed, I was too tired late last night to update the answer with readable code and have done so this morning.  The extra clarity that comes from being awake also lead me to catch the problem in my nsight build config that was causing (plausibly) false non-determinism. Thanks to @robertcrovella and @einpoklum for suggesting `volatile`, as that seems to work.  I've made another answer that's more to the point and plan to remove or downvote this one after confirmation of the other one's correctness rolls in.