# How do you keep data in fast GPU memory (l1/shared) across kernel invocations?

Tags: caching, cuda, gpu-shared-memory

How do you keep data in fast GPU memory across kernel invocations?

Let's suppose, I need to answer 1 million queries, each of which has about 1.5MB of data that's reusable across invocations and about 8KB of data that's unique to each query.

One approach is to launch a kernel for each query, copying the 1.5MB + 8KB of data to shared memory each time.  However, then I spend a lot of time just copying 1.5MB of data that really could persist across queries.

Another approach is to "recycle" the GPU threads (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49957384/3738356).  That involves launching one kernel that immediately copies the 1.5MB of data to shared memory.  And then the kernel waits for requests to come in, waiting for the 8KB of data to show up before proceeding with each iteration.  It really seems like CUDA wasn't meant to be used this way.  If one just uses managed memory, and volatile+monotonically increasing counters to synchronize, there's still no guarantee that the data necessary to compute the answer will be on the GPU when you go to read it.  You can seed the values in the memory with dummy values like -42 that indicate that the value hasn't yet made its way to the GPU (via the caching/managed memory mechanisms), and then busy wait until the values become valid.  Theoretically, that should work.  However, I had enough memory errors that I've given up on it for now, and I've pursued....

Another approach still uses recycled threads but instead synchronizes data via `cudaMemcpyAsync`, cuda streams, cuda events, and still a couple of volatile+monotonically increasing counters.  I hear I need to pin the 8KB of data that's fresh with each query in order for the `cudaMemcpyAsync` to work correctly.  But, the async copy isn't blocked -- its effects just aren't observable.  I suspect with enough grit, I can make this work too.

However, all of the above makes me think "I'm doing it wrong."  *How do you keep extremely re-usable data in the GPU caches so it can be accessed from one query to the next?*

Comment: I've been wondering if putting the data in the texture memory instead of the general memory might help.  Texture memory doesn't seem to be g.c.'d across kernel invocations.  However, I figure such a choice would affect my L1 availability... which isn't great on a P100 (situation should be much improved on the V100).  Also, it seems I can fit more in shared memory per SM than in the L1.

Comment: You can't. Technically all the _fast_ (on-chip) memories get invalidated upon kernel termination, mainly due to security reasons. Your best bet as you guessed is recycling the threads with a loop, for which you have to manually implement thread decomposition and inter-thread-block syncing.

Comment: In short, you cannot keep anything in shared across kernel invocations.  As a result you will run into approaches related to *persistent kernel* methodology (which you already wrote about in your last question on the CUDA tag.)  [Here](https://svail.github.io/persistent_rnns/) is another example.  Some aspects of cooperative groups in CUDA 9 are designed to help facilitate this sort of things (particularly a cooperative launch).

Answer (score 1):

- First of all to observe the effects of the streams and Async copying
  you definitely need to pin the host memory. Then you can observe
  concurrent kernel invocations "almost" happening at the same time.
  I'd rather used Async copying since it makes me feel in control of
  the situation.
- Secondly you could just hold on to the data in global memory and load
  it in the shared memory whenever you need it. To my knowledge shared
  memory is only known to the kernel itself and disposed after
  termination. Try using Async copies while the kernel is running and
  synchronize the streams accordingly. Don't forget to __syncthreads()
  after loading to the shared memory. I hope it helps.